# How to hide and show p:panel on commandbutton click

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

i have the following problem:

I'm new to JSF2 and primefaces.

I have a table in a page that will be populated with information, after the user enters a string and clicks a CommandButton. After clicking the button, I want it to be disabled until processing is over.

To disable the CommandButton I'm doing the following;

```
<p:commandButton update=":outPanel" widgetVar="btnSend" id="btnsend"
     value="Calcular" actionListener="#{calcBean.getTrfs}" 
     onclick="btnSend.disable()" oncomplete="btnSend.enable()" />
```

And then I have a panel where I want to show its contents:

```
<p:panel id="outPanel" widgetVar="outpanel">
         #{calcBean.result}
</p:panel>
```

How can I hide this outpanel when the page loads the first time?

How can I hide it when I click the CommandButton, and only show it again if the processing in my bean is successful?

Thanks.

Comment: PrimeFaces has an excellent solution for this common practice: blockUI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved,

i have to put

```
   closable="true" toggleable="true"
```

attributes in p:panel... Thanks

Comment: Maybe in 2012 this was correct answer, but in PF 7.0 I think it is not, for more details see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59481613/how-to-hide-ppanel-on-commandbutton-click

Answer (score 3):

I have checked following panel hide and show using p:commandButton in JSF,

please try following methods in JSF,

```
<p:panel id="button_panel" widgetVar="testPanel" closable="true" toggleable="true">
<h1>Testing</h1>
</p:panel>

<p:commandButton onclick="PF('testPanel').show()" value="Show Panel" type="button"/>

<p:commandButton onclick="PF('testPanel').hide();" value="Hide Panel" type="button"/>
```

Comment: It's better used ``PF('testPanel').toggle()``, That joins ``PF('testPanel').show()`` and ``PF('testPanel').show()``

Comment: @zhelon do you mean, that joins PF('testPanel').show() and PF('testPanel').close().

Comment: FYI: I tried that with PF 7.0 and it was not working - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59481613/how-to-hide-ppanel-on-commanbbutton-click

Answer (score 0):

to show the panel after the ajax request is finished try this:

```
 <p:commandButton update=":outPanel" widgetVar="btnSend" id="btnsend"
 value="Calcular" actionListener="#{calcBean.getTrfs}" 
 onclick="btnSend.disable()" oncomplete="btnSend.enable();outPanel.show();" />
```

Comment: I put the outpanel.show and the commandbutton stoped been disable... It stay enabled after click.

Comment: @RLuceac dint you want the commandbutton to enable after being processed and to show the panel ??

Comment: But when i put the outpanel.show() the button disables and never get enabled again

Comment: @RLuceac did u also add oncomplete="btnSend.enable();outPanel.show(); ??

Comment: I get a project with primefaces 6.2 when I use onclick , actioneListener never get fired,