# How to hide/show a panel conditionally in primefaces/jsf2 on commandButton click?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to hide/show `<p:panel>` on commandButton click with some condition ,I tried following

```
<h:form>
// some tag here
<p:commandButton value="EDIT" ajax="false"
                        onclick="if(#{bean.status == 'ACTIVE'}){editable.show();}"
                        actionListener="#{beanMgnt.edit}">
</h:form>
```

and  editable is a panel as

```
<p:panel widgetVar="editable" closable="true"
                toggleable="true" visible="false">
                // some tags here
            </p:panel
```

edit method is doing only sysout.

What I want when enduser clicks the button this panel will be visible with bean data populated with Editable text boxes.

I want to make visible this panel visible with button click.How to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide and show p:panel on commandbutton click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600170/how-to-hide-and-show-ppanel-on-commandbutton-click)

Comment: Suggested links doesnot resolve my issue

Comment: Yes , I want panel to visible when click on button

Comment: Use PF('editable').show() in onclick

Comment: In addition to selecting the widget by `PF('editable')` you should use ajax. Otherwise, your page will reload, thus the panel is invisible again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use a boolean attribute in your backing bean. In the panel you put : `visible="backingbean.yourAttribute"` and you use a method in your bean to control it via onclick.

```
onclick="backingbean.theMethod"
```

In the method, if your condition is verified, you can set the attribute to "true".

Comment: I want to make it visible on button click

Comment: Yes, when you click, it triggers the onclick, and call the method. In this method, you set a boolean to true, so you have visible=true in your panel. Isn't it working ?

Comment: I didn't find a way how to make that work with PF 7.0 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59481613/how-to-hide-ppanel-on-commanbbutton-click

Answer (score 1):

You also have to use update="<id>" in your button...
so,for example, you would need <p:commandButton...update="thepanelid".../> <p:panel id="thepanelid"...

Comment: I didn't find a way how to make that work with PF 7.0 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59481613/how-to-hide-ppanel-on-commanbbutton-click