# How to hide p:panel on CommandButton click

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I wanted to achieve what is written here - [How to hide and show p:panel on commandbutton click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600170/how-to-hide-and-show-ppanel-on-commandbutton-click) but it seems, that `hide()` is not available anymore...

What's the proper approach?

I tried `toggle()`, but it's not hiding it:

[image: Panel after toggle()]

Do I really have to have some `panelVisibile` property on backing bean and use `visible=#{.panelVisible}`?

I'm trying with PrimeFaces 7.0.

Project is based on https://github.com/Betlista/joinfaces-maven-jar-example

**index.xhtml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Primefaces Test</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:panel id="button_panel" widgetVar="testPanel" closable="true" toggleable="true">
            <h1>Testing</h1>
        </p:panel>

        <p:commandButton onclick="PF('testPanel').show()" value="Show Panel" type="button"/>

        <p:commandButton onclick="PF('testPanel').hide();" value="Hide Panel" type="button"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

**Result**

[image: hide is not a function error in console]

Even when I tried `PF('testPanel')` in browser's console, there is only `show()` and no `hide()`.

## Trying workaround

**test1.xhtml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Primefaces Test</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="form1">
        <p:panel id="button_panel" widgetVar="testPanel" closable="true" toggleable="true" visible="#{test1View.panelVisible}">
            <h1>Testing</h1>
        </p:panel>

        <p:commandButton value="Show Panel" actionListener="#{test1View.setPanelVisible(true)}" update="form1"/>

        <p:commandButton value="Hide Panel" actionListener="#{test1View.setPanelVisible(false)}" update="form1" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

**Test1View**

```java
package app;

import org.primefaces.PrimeFaces;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
//import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
//@SessionScoped
@ViewScoped
//@RequestScoped
public class Test1View implements Serializable {

    boolean panelVisible = false;

    public boolean isPanelVisible() {
        return panelVisible;
    }

    public void setPanelVisible(boolean panelVisible) {
        this.panelVisible = panelVisible;
        PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("form1:button_panel");
    }

}
```

...but it is not working = it is hidden/shown only after refresh...

Comment: Sorry, I thought it's clear, but I added all the details...

Comment: I think it it because you are missing scope from your bean.  You have it Named but not ViewScoped or RequestScoped so the value of panelVisible is getting reset because the bean is being recreated every time.

Comment: @Melloware thanks for a tip, but I tried `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped`, `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`, `javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped` and `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` but it didn't help, workaround is not functional

Comment: The method is close() so do `PF('testPanel').close()` instead of hide. Or you can use toggle() so `PF('testPanel').toggle()` which will show or hide it.

Comment: @Kukeltje I have no idea why you are so offensive, calm down ;-) I wrote above, that I tried toggle and from my point of view hide is not the same as close...

Comment: Then I suggest you make a feature request on the PF GitHub Issues for a hide method.  To me it really should be there if close does not do the same thing. and it should accept an "speed" value.

Answer (score 0):

## PF solution

In the end, I tried `close()` as well and I found it is kind of what I'm looking for, but it is a hide with effect:

[image: look and feel of panel on close()]

It is not true, that `toggle()` is the same as `close()` for a panel if visible:

[image: look and feel of panel on toggle()]

It results in ([test6.xhtml](https://github.com/Betlista/joinfaces-maven-jar-example/blob/so-hide-panel/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/test6.xhtml))

- `closeable="true"`
- `closeSpeed=0`
- toggleable not needed

```xml
<h:form>
    <p:panel id="button_panel" widgetVar="testPanel" closable="true" closeSpeed="0">
        <h1>Testing</h1>
    </p:panel>

    <p:commandButton onclick="PF('testPanel').show()" value="Show Panel" />

    <p:commandButton onclick="PF('testPanel').close();" value="Close Panel" />
</h:form>
```

## Alternative solution

**jQuery**: For that, I'm defining `testPanelJqId` as a class for the panel.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Primefaces Test</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="form1">
        <div class="testPanelJqId">
            <h1>Testing</h1>
        </div>

        <p:commandButton value="Show Panel" onclick="jQuery('.testPanelJqId').show()"/>

        <p:commandButton value="Hide Panel" onclick="jQuery('.testPanelJqId').hide()" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

it just does not feel like PrimeFaces approach... In such a setup, I do not need to use `p:panel` at all...

### PrimeFaces p:panel and id alternative

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Primefaces Test</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="form1">
        <p:panel id="panel1">
            <h1>Testing</h1>
        </p:panel>

        <p:commandButton value="Show Panel" onclick="jQuery(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('form1:panel1')).show()"/>

        <p:commandButton value="Hide Panel" onclick="jQuery(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('form1:panel1')).hide()" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

All the examples are available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Betlista/joinfaces-maven-jar-example/tree/so-hide-panel).

Comment: I'd like to know the reason for downvote, examples above are functional. Maybe not nice (that's why I asked this question), but the code above works in terms of showing/hiding panel...

Comment: In your "alternate" example you can just use `PF('panelWidget').jq.hide()` the `jq` object of widgets is the Jquery object for that.  So you don't have to do the ID with escapeClientId etc.